# Why is working after subscribe many time?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a 3 components

1. InvoicelistComponent
2. CreateinvoiceComponent
3. HeaderInvoiceComponent

InvoicelistComponent have function route to page CreateInvoice

```
  getInvoiceDetail(invoiceId: number) {
    this.router.navigate('mainmenu/invoice/createinvoice', invoiceId)
  }
```

CreateinvoiceComponent in ngOnInit get invoiceId , get data from api  and set data to service

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let checkMode = this.routerService.data === undefined || null ? false : true;
    if (checkMode === true) {
      this.spinner.show();
      let invoiceId = this.routerService.data;
      this.createInvoiceService.getdatainvoicebyid(invoiceId).subscribe(res => {
        let invoicemodel = new Invoice();
        invoicemodel = res;
        this.searchService.setdatainvoiceData(invoicemodel['result'][0]);
        this.spinner.hide();
      });
    }
  }
```

SearchService have function setdatainvoiceData

```
  public setInvoiceData = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  setdatainvoiceData(data: any) {
    this.setInvoiceData.next(data);
  }
```

HeaderInvoiceComponent in constructor have subscribe wait for data

```
this.searchService.setInvoiceData.subscribe(res => {
  if (res != null || res != undefined) {
    console.log(res);
    this.objRequestParam.InvoiceType = res.Invoiceheader.invoicetypeid
    this.objRequestParam.InvoiceSubType = res.Invoiceheader.invoicesubtypeid
    this.objRequestParam.InvoiceDate = res.Invoiceheader.invoicedate;
    this.objRequestParam.txtInvoiceNo =  res.Invoiceheader.invoiceno;
    this.radioValue = res.Invoiceheader.invoicereferencetypeid;
  }
});
```

Issue is when I click green icon in first time
after subscribe in HeaderInvoiceComponent working 2 round  (In image show 1 round because I check for null value)

[image]
[image]
Round 1 value is null
Round 2 value is not null
maybe Can I do it in one round? can anyone recommend?

and when I click back page and click green icon in second time but another item

why working 3 round ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, but I think you need subscribe to activatedRouter.paramMap: see https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments. What is your `routerService`? NOTE: If you want to use state to pass parameter (but in this case you need use navigateByUrl, check this link: https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to unsubscribe the previous subscription when navigating away from the current page. In each of your component, try adding below code.

```
export class InvoicelistComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(
    private svc: ServiceName
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.svc.setInvoiceData.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      ...
    }); 
  }
  
 ngOnDestroy() {
   this.destroy$.next(true);
   this.destroy$.complete();
 }
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: it work !! thank you but it working 2 round. round 1 null , round 2 get value Can it in one round?

Comment: This is because you are using BehaviorSubject. You can change it to Subject instead. BehaviorSubject by default sends the initial data directly to its subscriber.

Comment: What method would you recommend for another way?

Comment: For your case, just use Subject as below. However, I would strongly recommend to use a state management library like ngxs [link](https://www.ngxs.io/)

`public setInvoiceData = new Subject<any>(null);`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try changing `if (res != null || res != undefined)` to `if (res)`